# Undefined object when putting in throw new Error(error.response);

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to ask if why my object is getting undefined when I put it inside the throw new Error(error.response) but if outside I can get the exact value. Here's my code below:

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.validateUrlInToken()
    .then(this.onValidateUrlInTokenSuccess)
    .catch(this.onValidateUrlInTokenFail);
}

validateUrlInToken() {
  const tokenParams = {
    token: this.props.params.token,
  };

  return axios.post('/api/core/validate_token/', tokenParams);
}

onValidateUrlInTokenSuccess(response) {
  const { data } = response.data;
  const email = data.username;
  const userId = data.user_id;
  const lastLogin = data.last_login;

  this.setState({ email, userId, lastLogin });

  this.getSite()
    .then(this.onGetSiteSuccess)
    .catch(this.onGetSiteFail);
}

onValidateUrlInTokenFail(error) {
  console.log(error.response) // { data: { detail: 'Invalid Token' } }
  this.context.router.push('/login');
  throw new Error(error.response); // Undefined response
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: It may related with this.context.router.push('/login'); code block. Comment out this line then try it again

Answer (score 1):

try using callback instead

```
onValidateUrlInTokenFail(callback,error) {
  console.log(error.response) // { data: { detail: 'Invalid Token' } }
  this.context.router.push('/login');
  callback(new Error(error.response));
}
```

Comment: This will still try to use the undefined value of `error.response`.